# Custom form in iOS

Tags: iphone

I want to create a custom form that a user can fill out for ios, then email to themselves  or upload to cloud etc. What is the best way of approaching this?

Eg a gas engineer has to complete a gas safe certificate for his work.  He/she fills out the form on his device and then sends as email or uploads to cloud.  Creating the cert is no problem, capturing the entered data and emailing it as it appears on the screen seems to have me stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This website [CocoaControls](http://cocoacontrols.com) has quite a few custom views that you can leverage in your applications. Specifically, I found these controls: [IBAForms](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ibaforms) and [QuickDialog](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/quickdialog).

Comment: Thanks for that, checked those out and looked interesting, unfortunately i dont understand how to implement any of it to ios 5 or xcode

Answer (score 0):

What iOS version are you using? in iOS 5 there is a static cells mode that is excellent for creating forms in UITableView, see: http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=219&page=2 and http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2

Otherwise, you can still use Dynamic cells and create ifs to customize each cell in the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Personally, I'm not a big fan of custom libraries for this kind of job, but that's a personal preference :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Im Using IOS 5, I can create the form I just dont undertand how to capture the information so it can be emailed or shared...